# Files not being deleted on Windows 2008 share

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2008

Windows 2008 environment with domain.  All clients are Windows 7.
This is a newly configured domain.

On two client computers, files are deleted on the share.  Intermittently on a directory refresh the files will reappear.  Doing batch file removal ends up with some files being deleted and others withstanding (it isn't certain files, they are random).  The files cannot be opened (errors out with access denied).  When this happens I can see the files are still listed locally on the server but cannot be accessed there as well.  Using Process Explorer I can see there exist system file handlers for the files (attempting to remove the handle errors out with "handle cannot be found").

Interestingly, when the client computer from where the file was deleted is restarted the files will properly be deleted.  Ending explorer.exe and restarting it does not accomplish this, the computer has to be restarted.  I did not try ending certain services to try and narrow it down.

I've successfully repeated this issue with only one connection to the share and no files being accessed by any other client computers.  Nothing is under load, including the OS and the network.

The share was originally on a separate client computer. I transferred the share over to the server in hopes it would fix it; it obviously did not.

The problem is definitely on the client computer but I have not had success in finding anyone else who has had this issue.  I've checked system logs but there are no errors to report.  It's a new one for me and very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem ended up being Adobe's PDF previewer (which integrates with windows files explorer).  Switched clients to foxit and its previewer is properly releasing the files.

Adobe needs to push an update for this ASAP.